# DirectoryNotFoundException after Directory.Exists

Tags: c#, io

How can the following statement:

```
if (Directory.Exists(outputDestination) 
    && new DirectoryInfo(outputDestination).GetFiles().Count() > 0)
```

throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException`: Could not find a part of the path given I check directory exists before calling GetFiles()

Comment: Why theoretically it can't?

Comment: @Fabjan The posted code can most definitely throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException` as it's a perfect example of a TOCTOU bug.  It's almost an exact C# equivalent of the C code used in [the Wikipedia TOCTOU page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  Something else can delete the directory in the time between the check and the use.  Checks such as the posted code are, in reality, somewhere between useless and misleading.

Comment: FWIW it took me 1 minute to create a sample program that crashes with that specific exception on that specific if-statement by just forcing the race condition to occur - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/5f00f89616184eb7a2c413097841ca04

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I meant that with sample of code that OP has provided and without any additional information it shouldn't throw ex in most of cases

Comment: Another reason to avoid **all** "check-then-use" code: the check can not be identical to the use: the check is not the use. In this example, the directory may exist but the current user may not be able to read its contents.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And then we'd have an `AccessDenied` sort of exception

Comment: @Fabjan Didn't you just post "it shouldn't throw ex in most of cases"?  The posted code's "check-then-use" approach is completely flawed and can fail in many, many ways.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes but the OP was interested in a specific type of exception thrown and he didn't specify if this code is executed in multythreaded/multi-process environment. As an aside it very well may be that a "check-then-use" principle is flawed but it's used for things like logging, etc.

Comment: @Fabjan The posted code's "check-then-use" approach is so fundamentally broken - not merely "flawed" - that the bug it represents has an entire Wikipedia page dedicated to it.  Your "but people write bad code" defense of the practice is also fundamentally flawed.  Would you say code that allows buffer overflows or SQL injection is OK because - having been written - "it's used"? "Using bad code is OK because you're using it"?!?!?!  TOCTOU bugs such as the one in the OPs code have been used in many privilege escalation attacks, for example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 'bad' and 'good' are subjective definitions which also depend on specific problem that we try to resolve. This code (however imperfect it is) might work very well in *certain* scenario when for example we *know* for 100% that only *one* thread in a single process will access the folder. I'm not advocating for using this approach just saying "it depends on other things as well"

Comment: @Fabjan The code as posted assumes `Directory.Exists()` is sufficient to allow `DirectoryInfo(outputDestination).GetFiles().Count()`.  I've already posted one example (directory not readable) where that's not true.  Relying on assumptions such as "when for example we *know* for 100% ..." is a great way to end up with code that fails in unpredictable ways. While that "might work very well" for you, I have higher standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can the following statement:
>
> ```
> if (Directory.Exists(outputDestination) 
>    && new DirectoryInfo(outputDestination).GetFiles().Count() > 0)
> ```
>
> throw a DirectoryNotFoundException?

Your code can throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException` because you've created [a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use):

> In software development, **time of check to time of use** (TOCTTOU or TOCTOU, pronounced "tock too") is a class of software bugs caused by changes in a system between the checking of a condition (such as a security credential) and the use of the results of that check. This is one example of a race condition.

Just because the directory exists for the call to `Directory.Exists()`, that does not mean that it still exists for the call to `DirectoryInfo()`.

Comment: In general you can optimise this kind of code only one way, by checking for the negative condition and then not doing the rest, but for the positive condition you actually need to try the actual code, let it fail with an exception and catch those exceptions. So you could do `if (!Directory.Exists(...)) return;` but you cannot guarantee that the folder exists when you try to later use it, only that it existed at the time you tested for it first.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen True. That will avoid the race condition because it won't do the usage portion if the object doesn't exist. In the interest of simplicity, though, I wouldn't recommend doing such an optimization unless there are demonstrable performance impacts.

Comment: Totally agree with that.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that on a networked filesystem (or other similarly-slow filesystem), the `Directory.Exists()` optimization is often an _anti_-optimization, since it requires an additional network call before the _actual_ network call, and for small directories, the amount of data transferred might be identical for both. I've seen many scenarios in my company's code where `Directory.Exists()` or `File.Exists()` checks made the code slower, not faster. *tl;dr:* In nearly every case, you're far better off just catching the `DirectoryNotFoundException` than pre-checking.

Comment: Yes was a race condition caused by an asnychronous call deleting the directory. Have now marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

For a move operation across drive volumes, I encountered this. Even though the OP said that their answer was a race condition. There are other reasons that the exception can be thrown, such as too long of a file name. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directorynotfoundexception?view=net-5.0):

> The exception that is thrown when part of a file or directory cannot be found.

**when part of a file** is key. A check within a catch, will show that a long file name will give the `DirectoryNotFoundException`

```
try
{
    fromFile.CopyTo(toFile.FullName, toFile.Exists);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    // can occur for really long file names
    if (Math.Max(fromFile.FullName.Length, toFile.FullName.Length) >= 260)
    {
        try
        {
            // in 4.6.1 they added handling for long file names, but its weird
            string from = $"\\\\?\\{fromFile.FullName}";
            string to = $"\\\\?\\{toFile.FullName}";
            File.Copy(from, to, File.Exists(to));
            if (File.Exists(to))
            {
                File.Delete(from);
                Log("Success\n");
                continue;
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            Log("Failed\n");
            continue;
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```